# unable to add filter:a to ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

Im working on a video editing project and im using ffmpeg for video rendering

To play video before rendering i wana show it to user and i thought of using ffplay

```
ffplay -i C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/test.mp4 -filter:a "volume="1.0",atempo="1.0"" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/"1.0"*PTS,scale="1280*720"" -aspect 16:9 D:/videos.mp4output.mp4
```

but this is giving an error:

```
Failed to set value 'volume=1.0,atempo=1.0' for option 'filter:a': Option not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffplay only recognizes -vf/-af for video and audio filters respectively.

```
-af "volume=1.0,atempo=1.0"
```

Comment: thanks it worked <br> is their list where i can see these differences between ffmpeg and ffplay commands thanks a lot

Comment: Doc for ffplay is at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html

Comment: sir i have posted another query please check it once "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085953/merging-2-editing-videos-without-saving-them-using-ffmpeg" Thank you