# merging 2 editing videos without saving them using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyqt, pyqt5, video-editing

I want to combine 2 videos assume even they are edited among themselves

How normally we do

video 1:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter:a "volume=0.0" test1.mp4
```

video 2:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -filter:a "volume=10.0" test2.mp4
```

now I can combine them using

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -i test2.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] out.put.mp4
```

So my question is, Is there a way to make this 3 steps process into 1 step and without saving files of step 1 and step 2

I do know that we can combine into one using && but my main query is there a way to do without saving the files of video1 and video2 that edited files

Hope I'm a bit clear with my query

Question edited/added:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter:a "volume=8.0,atempo=4.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/4*PTS" -s 640x480 test.mkv
```

can we do all these options also in the merge command(operations like change video Speed, resolution, rotation, framerate, and trim)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the volume filters before feeding the audio streams to concat.

`ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -i test2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]volume=0.0[a0];[1:a:0]volume=10.0[a1];[0:v:0][a0][1:v:0][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] output.mp4`

Comment: thanks a lot, for that can we also change video Speed, resolution, rotation, framerate can these also be changed. If possible please write the command it helps a lot thanks again!

Comment: sir I have updated the question once check the "Question edited/added: part" thanks a lot sir